# Method to create UIButtons

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

this is my first post, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have to create a number of UIButtons programmatically, which I have done, but the code gets quite messy when there are alot of buttons so I have written a method that will take a UIbutton, string and UIcolor as input and set the rest of the UIButton attributes for me.  The problem is the buttons don't seem to be created.  Is what I'm trying possible or am I going about it the wrong way.

The method

```
-(void)makeButton:(UIButton *)name titleOfButton:(NSString *)title buttonColor:(UIColor *)color {

    name =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(400,400,150,100))];
    [name setAlpha:(0.5)];
    [name setBackgroundColor: color];
    [name setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    name.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    name.titleLabel. numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
    name.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    name.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [myView addSubview:name];
}
```

and to call the method

```
[self makeButton:JDLabel
   titleOfButton:@"JD"
     buttonColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The method has been declared in the header file and the buttons at the top of the class.

Comment: Are you doing anything with that JDLabel after you call this method? The thing is as you wrote this method, this "name" parameter is totally useless, you can delete it. If you want the button on the parameter JDLabel after calling the method there are better ways..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  To answer you and @hemant I have +10 buttons which I've had to create programatically.  Its part of an AR app I'm playing around with and the buttons are centered on the View from another method when needed.  The main reason to do this is just to unclutter my code and make it easier to add more buttons later on.

Comment: Well, what you are doing is correct to some point. Try debugging if your "myView" is not nil and if it is a correct view. And as it was pointed out there are some issues. You always use the same position of the button, "name" parameter is useless, unless using ARC you have a memory leak in the method, you have no direct reference to newly created button, there is no target added to buttons... Ill post you some code as an answer to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some code to get you started. This will work if you paste it to your view controller, generally put it in the view you want but change "self.view" to "self" or any view you want as long as you have the reference to it. Just call "addSomeButtons" on "viewDidLoad" or as some target..

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"button %d pressed", sender.tag+1);
}
- (void)makeButtonWithtitle:(NSString *)title andColor:(UIColor *)color atPositionIndex:(NSInteger)index {    
    const CGFloat buttonHeight = 60.0f;
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f, buttonHeight*index, 300.0f, buttonHeight)];    

    button.tag = index;
    [button setAlpha:(0.5)];
    [button setBackgroundColor: color];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    button.titleLabel. numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
    button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [button release];
}
- (void)addSomeButtons {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        [self makeButtonWithtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button %d", i+1] andColor:[UIColor greenColor] atPositionIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Anyway what you are trying to do is very common and very possible. For instance I never ever ever use the interface builder.

Comment: Thanks for your time, pretty much what I needed

Answer (score 0):

set the different tag  value of to separate the button from another button like:
button.tag = 1;

here you should use variable like 
in .h

```
int i ;
```

in .m

```
 button.tag = i;
```

and set the frame size of one button to another button

```
UIButton *name = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRectangle];
name.frame = CGRectMake(10*i,10*i,150,100);

i++;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into tags

Answer (score 0):

UIButtons are getting created but getting overlapped over each other.. u just need to change the frame with every method call too.. 400,400 will create the button off screen .. i don't think thats what u want .. try something like 160,240

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating the Buttons in Interface Builder, which I find much more convenient for setting the size, colors etc.

You can then reference the buttons in the code via either with an `IBOutlet` per Button or with an `IBOutletCollection`, which let's you "group" a number of `UIView`s in one Outlet:

- Simply create your `UIButton`s in Interfacebuilder and place them *next* to your main view, so that they won't be displayed initially.
- `CMD + Click` all buttons and `CTRL + Drag` to your `.h` file and create an `IBOutletCollection` which will eventually look like this in your code:

  ```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *allMyButtonsFromIB;
  ```
- Now you can access the buttons in the implementation via `self.allMyButtons`, which is an `NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)createButtonWithTitle:(NSString*)title andColor:(UIColor*)color andFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    UIButton *lButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [lButton setFrame:frame];
    [lButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    lButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    [lButton setBackgroundColor:color];

    [self.view addSubview:lButton];
    lButton = nil;
}
```

You can change the frame values to put the buttons at appropriate positions on the view.